# Style names in gtksourceview

Tags: gtk

In `/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/kate.xml`, I see this line:

```
  <style name="draw-spaces"                 foreground="#d3d7cf"/>
```

What does `draw-spaces` mean? Is there some resource that explains this and other terms used in the styles found in `/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles/`?

(There's a lot of information on syntax highlighting but I don't want that.)

Answer (score 0):

[**`id (mandatory)`**](https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/lang-reference.html#id-1.3.3.7)

> > Identifier for the style. This is used in the current language to refer to this style and must be unique for the current document. It can contain a string of letters, digits, hyphens ("-") and underscores ("_").

You can also find more information [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/NewLanguage).

Hope that helps.